# "Connection refused" exception while sending push notification to GCM server

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Sometime getting connection refused exception while sending push notification to GCM server.

Push notification Code:

```
getSender().send(message, "registrationIDs", 5);
```

Above line throws connection refused exception.

Stacktrace:

```
[java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
        at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1104)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:998)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1282)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1257)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
        at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.post(Sender.java:479)
        at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.post(Sender.java:458)
        at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Sender.java:170)
        at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.send(Sender.java:121)
        at com.novell.zenworks.mobile.pushnotification.GCMPushNotificationSender.sendNotification(GCMPushNotificationSender.java:164)
        at com.novell.zenworks.loader.modules.DoMobilePushNotificationQueueActionHandler.sendPushNotificationToMobileDevices(DoMobilePushNotificationQueueActionHandler.java:451)
        at com.novell.zenworks.loader.modules.DoMobilePushNotificationQueueActionHandler.processAction(DoMobilePushNotificationQueueActionHandler.java:361)
        at com.novell.zenworks.loader.modules.queue.runner.QueueThreadWorker.processAction(QueueThreadWorker.java:220)
        at com.novell.zenworks.loader.modules.queue.runner.QueueThreadWorker.run(QueueThreadWorker.java:146)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: `ConnectException` usually occures when there is something wrong with the connection between the client and the server. Please check your internet connection and verify your device can connect to or access the gcm servers.

Comment: Also check your firewall settings.